# How to communicate between Pc c# and siemens RF260R using the Protocol3964R from siemens?

Tags: c#, .net, siemens

i have a Siemens RF260R (which is a reader) that i need to communicate with, to read some tags.

This device uses Serial Communication to send and receive data. I have my pc with c# and visual studio. I know it uses `115200` as baud rate, stop bits `1`, data bits `8`, parity `Odd`, flow control `None`.

I need help on the communication part. For example how to communicate using the protocol 3964R from siemens? I found so little about that protocol, does someone know something more?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some documents found:

https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/160/7425160/att_2408/v1/T3964R_Win95-NT_e.pdf

https://www.opcturkey.com/uploads/siemens-s5-3964r-manual.pdf

https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/12932189/differences-between-protocols-3964(r)-and-rk-512?dti=0&lc=en-UA

[https://cdn.logic-control.com/docs/Wonderware/Device%20Connectivity/DA%20and%20IO%20Servers/Siemens%203964R%20User's%20Guide.PDF](https://cdn.logic-control.com/docs/Wonderware/Device%20Connectivity/DA%20and%20IO%20Servers/Siemens%203964R%20User%27s%20Guide.PDF)

You can ask Siemens for the protocol reference.